# Creating Docker image and running as service in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a JSP website. I am building DevOps pipeline. I am looking for help to integrate Jenkins with the Docker.

1. I already have docker file which does task of Deploying war file to the tomcat server.
   (Command1)
2. Through the command line I can run the docker file and create an image.
3. I can run created image as a service and able to browse the website.
   (Command2)

I want to do these two steps in Jenkins. I need your help to integrate these two commands in Jenkins, so that I need not to run these two commands manually one after other.

Comment: This is not really on-topic for SO. Maybe research on https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the ["Docker Pipeline Plugin"](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-workflow) for that.

For the first command, you can have a stage that runs:

```
myImage = docker.build("my-image:my-tag")
```

If you need you can have another stage where you can run some tests inside the image with:

```
myImage.inside {
  sh './run-test.sh'
}
```

Finally, you can push the image to the repository to your repository with:

```
docker.withRegistry('https://your-registry.com', 'credentials_id') { //use a second parameter if you repository requires authentication
    myImage.push('new_tag') //You can push it with a new tag
}
```

Please note that if you wanna use the `docker.*` methods in a declarative pipeline you must do it inside a `script` step or in a function.

(More info in the [plugin's user guide](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/))

For the second command, you only have to update the running image in the server. For doing that you have a lot of options (`docker service update` if you're using Docker Swarm, for example) and I think that part is outside of the scope of this post.